# Route Model Binding using resource return empty array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi I'm trying to use Route Model Binding using `Route::resource(..)` but when I try to return the model it is return as empty array `[]`. Here is my route :

```
Route::resource('application','ApplicationController');
```

and from the view index.blade.php I successfully show all the data and linked them to to edit.blade.php like this :

```
@foreach ($appVersions as $appVersion)
                      <tr>
                        {{-- Type AppVersion --}}
                        <td>{{ $appVersion->type }}</td>

                        {{-- Message Alert --}}
                        <td>{{ $appVersion->alert }}</td>
                        {{-- Version --}}
                        <td>{{ $appVersion->version }}</td>
                        {{-- Link --}}
                        <td>{{ $appVersion->link }}</td>
                        {{-- Plaform --}}
                        <td>{{ $appVersion->platform }}</td>
                        {{-- Action --}}
                        <td><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil cursor-hand" href="{{ route('application.edit',$appVersion) }}"></a></td>
                      </tr>
@endforeach
```

So I try to test to pass the model to edit page as you can see above `route('application.edit',$appVersion)` and try to directly return the model from the controller, this is my ApplicationController :

```
public function index()
    { //index fucntion to shows all the data appVersion
      try{
        // $data['appVersion'] = AppVersion::all();
        $appVersion = AppVersion::find(1);
        return view('application.index', compact('appVersion'));
      }catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
        return response()
                ->json([
                    'status'=>'failed',
                    'status_code'=>500,
                    'message' => 'An unexpected error has occurred on the server. Please contact server administrator.'
                  ], 500);
      }

    }

public function edit(AppVersion $appVersion)
    {//edit function to showing edit page
      // if I return $appVersion here it will return [].
      $type = ['Major'=>2, 'Minor'=>1];
      return view('application.edit',compact('appVersion','type'));
    }
```

so I've read the documentation about [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding) but it is only showing the sample using the specific route like **GET**.

I've seen and checked [neontsunami project](https://github.com/dwightwatson/neontsunami) it uses  `Route::resource(...)` for Route Model Binding. I'm kinda lost here, and try to figure and where did I miss ?

**NOTE** : I'm using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the same type-hinted variable name. In your case `$application`.

I recommend the following updates to your code:

#### routes.php

```
Route::resource('applications','ApplicationController');
```

#### ApplicationController.php

```
public function edit(AppVersion $application)
    {
      // if I return $appVersion here it will return [].
      $type = ['Major'=>2, 'Minor'=>1];
      return view('application.edit',compact('application','type'));
    }
```

Comment: this is works, but since the docs do not mention this any another approach?

Comment: It's mentioned in the documents, that you have to type hint your variables.

Comment: oh yeah you're right, its my bad doesnt fully understand them

Answer (score 0):

You're saying the docs only mention a **GET** route, but that seems to be exactly what you need. The route you are calling in your Blade view is this:

```
GET /application/{application}/edit
```

Now the only parameter it expects is `application`; you are passing it `$appVersion`.
So in your Controller method you can access your route parameter, as shown above. This works out-of-the-box with Laravel if you typehint a Model in your Controller method.
However, if you want to bind a parameter that's not an id to a Model instance you should do so in your **RouteServiceProvider**, like this:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    // route bindings
    $router->bind('application', function ($appVersion) {
        return Application::where('version', $appVersion)->first();
    });
}
```